# iOS table view cell highlight border bug

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, border

I highlight my table cell border with this function:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if(currentIndexPath != indexPath){
        [self clearCellRowBorder];
        CGColorRef cyan = [UIColor colorWithRed: 0.0f/255.0f green: 255.0f/255.0f blue: 255.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f].CGColor;
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        [cell.contentView.layer setBorderColor: cyan];
        [cell.contentView.layer setBorderWidth:2.0f];
        currentIndexPath = indexPath;
    }
}
```

let say I have many rows, that beyond the screen size so I need to scroll to bottom see the further row. The problem I met is when I select first row the first row is highlighted all is ok but then when I scroll to bottom to see other unseen row, the one of the unseen row is highlighted too. So any one could help me about this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neo,

As you have already saved selcted index path in currentIndexPath,

You can do,

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
 //after creating cell :)
 if(currentIndexPath != indexPath){
    [self clearCellRowBorder];
   }
 else {
     CGColorRef cyan = [UIColor colorWithRed: 0.0f/255.0f green: 255.0f/255.0f blue: 255.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f].CGColor;
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell.contentView.layer setBorderColor: cyan];
    [cell.contentView.layer setBorderWidth:2.0f];
 }
}
```

That should do your job :) Happy coding :)

Comment: I know this way too but is there a better way to fix it?

Comment: @neo : This is the easiest way possible :) You must be aware of the fact that cell gets re used when user scrolls through tableView :) So your selected cell gets re-used hence it shows as selected :)  Insted blindly rendering or returning a cell you can check whether it should really be selected or not :) That is the simplest solution possible, unless you want to override the tableView cells properties or methods :)

Answer (score 0):

The table view cells are being "Reused" for performance. So the cell you see highlighted is the same cell being reused.

To fix this you can override UITableViewCell method **prepareForRese** and set the highlighted back to false(NO).

**Edit**
example:

```
- (void)prepareForReuse {
    [cell.contentView.layer setBorderWidth:0.0f];
}
```

Comment: Sorry I edited my answer, the method is called if you subclass UITableViewCell. If not, you can use willDisplayCell to set back to default.

Comment: Did you subclass UITableViewCell?

Comment: table cell method was a delegate method